# Preparing for an empty database in ggplot2 in R shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am using ggplot to visualise data from a weather station, I have it set up so that the users can select a Date Range and chance between devices and everything works well. However, they can select dates outside of the range of the data in the database and this obviously gives an error. I have been trying to using tryCatch and replacing it when an empty graph (Or anything) with the a title "Data Range unavailable" but I have not had any luck yet.

My question is, what is the best way to communicate to the users that there is no data in the Data base, without an ugly error message?

Cheers

I have tried tryCatch, I believe this will be the solution but I have failed at implementing it correctly so far

This is the code I use to show the timeseries data of Battery and temperature, this is working well providing there is data in the database.

```
   data <- get_data()
   s = data[input$x1_rows_selected[1],1] #Value for row selected in a DataTable
   graph <- influx_select(con = con,
                          db = session$userData$user$username,
                          field_keys = "*",
                          measurement = s,
                          group_by = "*",
                          order_desc = TRUE,
                          return_xts = FALSE,
                          where = paste0("time > ", "'",input$daterange2[1],"'", " AND TIME < ", "'",input$daterange2[2],"'"))
   df <- data.frame(graph)
   data <- as.numeric(unlist(df[input$dataInput1]))
   time1 = unlist(df["time"])
   TimeStamp <- anytime(time1)

   # plot(1:3, main = s) %This was purely testing purposes
#Changing the ylim based on the two expected limits, will likely look into making this more dynamic at a later date, but not an issue atm. 
#This is the area where I would like to add a tryCatch or something in order to catch any errors
   if(input$dataInput1 != "Battery"){
     ggplot(df, aes(y=data, x=TimeStamp))+ geom_line(size = 1.5, color = "darkblue") + ylab(input$dataInput1) + xlab("Time") +
       ggtitle(label = paste0(input$dataInput1, " over time")) +
       theme( # Hide panel borders and remove grid lines
         panel.border = element_blank(),
         panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
         panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
         # Change axis line
         axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
       geom_area(fill = "lightgrey") + ylim(0,50)
   } else {
     ggplot(df, aes(y=data, x=TimeStamp))+ geom_line(size = 1.5, color = "darkblue") + ylab(input$dataInput1) + xlab("Time") +
       ggtitle(label = paste0(input$dataInput1, " over time")) +
       theme( # Hide panel borders and remove grid lines
         panel.border = element_blank(),
         panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
         panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
         # Change axis line
         axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
       geom_area(fill = "lightgrey") + ylim(0,5)}
 })
```

Current error on empty database is:
Error: undefined columns selected
And I would like to say in one way or another "Data not available"
It could be outside the DateRange, or they might have one sensor with temperature and no humidity and one with just humidity, if they clicked between table rows then it could just be selecting a field_key (from influxdbr) that does not exist.

Comment: You could go this way: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/validation.html

Comment: Perfect! Only took like 1 minute to figure out and implement, cheers.